# After upgraded to jasper 6.3.1 continuous sub report are not working

Tags: jasper-reports

After upgraded to Jasper version 6.3.1, few of our reports are not working. Especially the sub reports continues for multiple pages. Below is the exception stack

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.commons.javaflow.Continuation.suspend()Ljava/lang/Object;
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRContinuationSubreportRunner.suspend(JRContinuationSubreportRunner.java:79) ~[jasperreports-javaflow-6.3.1.jar:6.3.1]
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.FillerSubreportParent.suspendSubreportRunner(FillerSubreportParent.java:153) ~[jasperreports-javaflow-6.3.1.jar:6.3.1]
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.FillerSubreportParent.addPage(FillerSubreportParent.java:133) ~[jasperreports-javaflow-6.3.1.jar:6.3.1]
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.addPageToParent(JRBaseFiller.java:1309) ~[jasperreports-javaflow-6.3.1.jar:6.3.1]
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.addPage(JRVerticalFiller.java:1830) ~[jasperreports-javaflow-6.3.1.jar:6.3.1]
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillPageBreak(JRVerticalFiller.java:1917) ~[jasperreports-javaflow-6.3.1.jar:6.3.1]
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillColumnBreak(JRVerticalFiller.java:1946) ~[jasperreports-javaflow-6.3.1.jar:6.3.1]
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillDetail(JRVerticalFiller.java:724) ~[jasperreports-javaflow-6.3.1.jar:6.3.1]
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillReportContent(JRVerticalFiller.java:275) ~[jasperreports-javaflow-6.3.1.jar:6.3.1]
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillReport(JRVerticalFiller.java:119) ~[jasperreports-javaflow-6.3.1.jar:6.3.1]
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:582) ~[jasperreports-javaflow-6.3.1.jar:6.3.1]
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.BaseReportFiller.fill(BaseReportFiller.java:396) ~[jasperreports-javaflow-6.3.1.jar:6.3.1]
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillSubreport.fillSubreport(JRFillSubreport.java:732) ~[jasperreports-javaflow-6.3.1.jar:6.3.1]
```

We are using "commons-javaflow-20060411.jar" jar file, if i downgrade this jar file to "commons-javaflow-1066591.jar" its working fine.

Any suggestions, Do we need to downgrade to make it work, or its issue introduced in jasper 6.3.1.

Comment: You should post the small sample to reproduce a problem (main report + subreport). Which jars are in cp?

Comment: I have below jars in classpath:

Comment: I have these jars in class path: commons-javaflow-20060411.jar , jasperreports-javaflow-6.3.1.jar , jasperreports-functions-6.3.1.jar , jasperreports-fonts-6.3.1.jar.

Comment: It works fine with version 6.2.2, But that version has some applet loading related issues. so i moved to 6.3.1, which solved that applet issue but introduces new issues.  This happens only to those reports having sub report data continues for multiple pages.

Comment: I am using the JRContinuationSubreportRunnerFactory, set it through code as shown below.

Comment: jrPropertiesUtil.setProperty("net.sf.jasperreports.subreport.runner.factory",
                "net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRContinuationSubreportRunnerFactory");

Comment: You should [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/41296106/edit) post

Comment: Can you also try the version at https://jaspersoft.jfrog.io/jaspersoft/repo/org/apache/commons/commons-javaflow/20160505/?

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked with commons-javaflow-20160505.jar